# QML Issues with customized ComboBox

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, hsqml

Solved:

Edit: as derM commented, setting anchors.fill: parent and deleting the other anchor values fixes the second issue.

Edit2: The incorrect widths was due to the width in customcombobox being set to `iterations.width` instead of `parent.width`

I've written a combobox style, and I have a couple of issues.

The first, is that for one of my comboboxes, the highlight "effect" (the change in color) doesn't apply to the whole item. Wheras it does apply fine to my other combobox. See pic:

[image]

The grid code:

```
GridLayout
{
    id: grid

    columns: 3

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.margins: 10

    height: 80

    Label
    {
        font.pointSize: 12
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Shuffle Type"
    }

    Label
    {
        font.pointSize: 12
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Iterations"
    }

    Label
    {
        font.pointSize: 12
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Launch Test"
    }

    CustomComboBox
    {
        id: shuffleType

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.minimumWidth: 150

        property string value: shuffleType.currentText

        model: ["RandomIndex", "KnuthShuffle"]

        dropDownText: shuffleType.displayText
    }

    CustomComboBox
    {
        id: iterations

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.minimumWidth: 150

        property int value: Number(iterations.currentText)

        currentIndex: 2

        model: [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]

        dropDownText: iterations.displayText
    }

    Button
    {
        id: goButton

        enabled: guiEnabled

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.minimumWidth: 150

        text: "Go"

        contentItem: Text
        {
            text: goButton.text

            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

            font.pointSize: 15

            opacity: enabled ? 1.0: 0.3
        }

        onClicked: 
        {
            testShuffle(shuffleType.value, iterations.value)
        }
    }
}
```

The combobox code:

```
// CustomComboBox.qml

ComboBox
{
    property alias dropDownText: dropDown.text

    enabled: guiEnabled

    delegate: ItemDelegate
    {
        id: item

        width: iterations.width

        contentItem: Text
        {
            text: modelData
            font.pointSize: 15
        }

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            hoverEnabled: true
            propagateComposedEvents: true

            onClicked: mouse.accepted = false
            onPressed: mouse.accepted = false
            onReleased: mouse.accepted = false
            onDoubleClicked: mouse.accepted = false
            onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = false
            onPressAndHold: mouse.accepted = false

            onEntered:
            {
                item.highlighted = true
            }

            onExited:
            {
                item.highlighted = false
            }
        }
    }

    contentItem: Text
    {
        id: dropDown

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

        font.pointSize: 15
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0: 0.3
    }
}
```

The second is that to get my text to correctly center, I have to cause a binding loop:

```
QML CustomComboBox: Binding loop detected for property "baselineOffset"
```

Here's the code causing the binding loop:

```
contentItem: Text
{
    id: dropDown

    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

    font.pointSize: 15
    opacity: enabled ? 1.0: 0.3
}
```

If just set the anchors I get this:

[image]

If I just set the alignment I get this:

[image]

It's a bit hard to tell, but on the second one it's not exactly centred.

Here's what it looks like when both values are set:

[image]

I guess I'm getting a binding loop because I shouldn't be setting both, maybe they depend on each other? I'm not sure how to properly centre my text without it.

Comment: Set `anchors.fill: parent` and the alignments.

Comment: @derM That worked, thanks! I'd say post your comment as an answer and I'd mark it correct but I'm not sure if that's the right etiquette when I had two questions. I probably should have made them two separate questions.